# Union and Null Behaviour

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know how does Null behave in Union I have two tables ATest and B, Both having two NULL values each but on Union only one NULL is included.

Table ATest

| ids |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| NULL |
| NULL |

Table B

| ID | Mobile |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1234 |
| 3 | NULL |
| 6 | 7982 |
| 7 | 454545 |
| 3 | NULL |
| NULL | 2345 |
| NULL | 23232 |

Query

```
select ids
from ATEST
UNION 
SELECT ID FROM B
```

Results of Union

| Null |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |

Results of Union All

| 1 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 3 |
| NULL |
| NULL |

Comment: `UNION` without `ALL` eliminates duplicates and (contrary to regular comparison logic that involves `NULL`, but in line with the other set operators) it does consider different `NULL`s the same. Weirdly enough [this isn't documented where it should be](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql), but then again we can now submit corrections to the docs. (I can't sign in at the moment, but anyone else could.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert [Documented on `EXCEPT/INTERSECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) along with a lot of other notes on set operators *"When comparing column values for determining DISTINCT rows, two NULL values are considered equal."*

Comment: @JeroenMostert, also noted in the [SELECT documentation under DISTINCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but I agree this should be called out on the UNION page too.